# I want to print the last level of the triangle only

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
x = 5
l = [1]

for i in range(x):

    print(l)
    newlist = []
    newlist.append(l[0])

    for i in range(len(l) - 1):
        newlist.append(l[i] + l[i+1])

    newlist.append(l[-1])
    l=newlist
```

The above code giving me output as a right-angle triangle only.

Output :

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
```

But I want to print the last level of the triangle only. But I don't know how to achieve it.
Please help me with this.

Desired Output :

```
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
```

Comment: Think: what part of your code is responsible for printing the levels of the triangle? Why does it print all of them? Can you think of a point in the code where you could do the printing, such that it only happens once? Preferably, one where the `l` list has the values for the last line of the triangle?

Answer (score 1):

Pull the `print()` call outside of the loop. And you actually need one less iteration to get the result, so change `x` to `x - 1` in the `for ...` line.

```py
x = 5
l = [1]

for i in range(x - 1):
    newlist = []
    newlist.append(l[0])
    for i in range(len(l) - 1):
        newlist.append(l[i] + l[i+1])
    newlist.append(l[-1])
    l=newlist

print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the line `print(l)` to be outside of the for loop, to make sure you're only printing after it completes

Answer (score 0):

You are printing inside of your loop, between each element being added. If you only want to print the final result, move the print to after the loop.

```py
x = 5
l = [1]
for i in range(x):
    newlist = []
    newlist.append(l[0])
    for i in range(len(l) - 1):
        newlist.append(l[i] + l[i+1])
    newlist.append(l[-1])
    l=newlist
print(l)
```

Comment: if I am printing outside the loop then output is coming wrong. the code is based on pascal triangle and if I am printing outside the loop so for x=5 output is coming as [1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1] instead of [1, 4, 6, 4, 1]

Comment: @Nikki2000 In your original code, you were printing before you add the new element, so you never saw the result of the list iteration. Now, you are printing after. So change `x = 5` to `x = 4`.